# init method pattern

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am having problems understanding what/how this works. it seems odd assigning self to return from the init message

```
- (id)init
{
    if((self=[super init])) {
       //code here for setting up
    }

    return self;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `init` method first assigns  the implicit `self` local variable (`self` is one of the two hidden arguments passed to methods) to the return value of the superclass's *designated initializer*. The reason behind this is that initializers can return a different object than the one that received the message, for example, when it is not possible to initialize the receiver correctly or when an existing instance is returned to avoid the need to initialize a new one.

After `self` is set, the `if` statement ensures that instance variables are only initialized if `self` is not `nil`. If `self` is `nil`, accessing the memory for the instance variables may be an error. Very few classes return `nil` but still it is a valid return value.

This is described in [Implementing an Initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4).