# iOS generated function structure for initWithNibName

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I often use the `initWithNibName` function to initialize stuff in my view controllers.  I am just noticing that the generated `initWithNibName` function does a nil check on `self`.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if(self) {
    //do some initializing
  }
  return self;
}
```

**Why is there a nil check for `self` and if not nil run initialization code?  Will this `if-statement` ever be false?  Why is apple insisting i do a nil check here?**

Comment: The reason for using the `if (self)` pattern is discussed in ["Handling Initialization Failure"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13).

Comment: should post this as the answer IMO! thanks for the link

Comment: I followed your advise and reposted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment above, the reason for using the `if (self)` pattern is discussed in ["Handling Initialization Failure"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13).

This pattern is not specific of `initWithNibName:`, it applies to initializer methods in general.

The `if` statement is used to avoid initializing the instance variables if `self` is `nil`. This is important because accessing the memory for the instance variables  if `self` is `nil` may be an error.

See also this question: [init method pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799771/init-method-pattern/6799839#6799839)

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, if any case arises when your nib is not loaded due to 'whatever' reason, there wont be any sense of initializing the controller, and so

a self.backgroundcolor = [UIColor blackColor]; will only be executed when self is not 'nil'.

Otherwise, the method will just return 'nil'

Answer (score 1):

If suddenly the system is for instance out of memory or some other issue arrises so your nib-file is not loaded and your views is not loaded into memory the nil check will make your viewcontroller exit gracefully instead of crashing.

The system will always try to grant your requests as much as possible ofcourse, but you still have to be ready for the day that it doesn't.